# <span> in <li> appearing below the bullet

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

If you open up this page in Chrome it's fine: http://www.dsi-usa.com/test/about.php

However in Firefox and Internet Explorer it doesn't work. I had found a thread earlier that suggested resetting the `<li>` to `padding: 0`. I did that and nothing happened. Any ideas on why? I'm thinking because the items are wrapped in a `span`, but that was done to separate the bullet color and text color.

```
#about-facts ul
{
    text-align:left;
    list-style-position:inside;
    color:#c60606;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding: 0;
}

#about-facts li
{
    font-size:15px;
}

#about-facts li span
{
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
display: block;
```

From the spans

Comment: thank you very much sir, that helps a load. In the event that I wanted the spans to be blocks (lets say to apply a background color) how would I have been able to solve this? Or would that not be an option?

Comment: I will, just had to wait 4 minutes to do so.

Comment: why not set the background color on the li instead of on the span!